# why this exception is coming : One or more errors occurred. at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, parallel.foreach

I am developing a task scheduler where I am fetching data from more than 200 queries and running these queries in Parallel.foreach loop.
But I am getting the below error:

> One or more errors occurred. at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body,
>   Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IList`1
>   list, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Action`1 body) at PFMSAccountJob.JobMethods.AppService.runService() in
>   C:\SVN\PFMSToPFG_RAWDbJob\PFMSToPFG_RAWDbJob\JobMethods\AppService.cs:line
>   95 Void ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)

I have tried with Cancellation token and Cancellation token source but still getting the same issue.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(queries, query =>
                         {

                           qry = query.Replace(Convert.ToString("TmpOblId"), val);
                             dt = DBUtil.ExecSelectMultipleSQL(accIdqryConnNode.ToString(), qry);

                             DataTable dtCopy = dt.Copy();
                             ds.Tables.Add(dtCopy);


                         });
```

Kindly help with this issue. As whenever I am getting this issue the task scheduler gets terminated automatically

Comment: `DataTables` are not thread safe, i cant tell here whats going on, but this **"might"** be the issue

Comment: If I guess correctly, DataTables are not thread safe. Maybe try placing a breakpoint in your first line so you can see what happens when it gets called? I'm thinking you probably don't have the database connection in some threads

Comment: @StevenLemmens: Yes it may be the issue of database connection but sometimes  I am getting this issue, not for all queries. can you please suggest me how it can be resolved? thanks

Comment: DataTables are not thread safe, so you can't do this like you're doing it now. Without more context on what you're trying to do, this is very hard to help with

Comment: is this anything related to parallel.foreach so that I can change the loop or any alternate solution to this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's probably related to the parallel.foreach.  You can test that by changing it to a regular foreach and seeing if you still run into the error.  Obviously, it will take longer to run.

Comment: Both `qry` and `dt` are global variables modified from multiple tasks. Which query is going to run in each iteration? Which table is going to be added to the dataset?  In any case, `Parallel.ForEach` won't accelerate slow SQL queries. Whatever the *real* problem with SQL is, `Parallel.ForEach` won't fix it

Comment: Besides, `DataSet` isn't thread safe. Just *don't* use it from inside `Parallel.ForEach`. If you want to store results, use a `ConcurrentQueue` and push each result in there.  Define all variables (qry, dt) *locally* to avoid mixing up queries and tables

Comment: Thank you for your help..will definitely try as you have described.